# Button B on micro:bit always pushed

Tags: bbc-microbit

I’m programming a micro:bit (in Ada) at the bare-metal level, that is, I’m addressing the nrf51 registers directly.

I have no trouble with button A, GPIO pin 17: it’s configured as

```
dir => input, 
input => connect,
pull => pullup,
drive => s0s1, 
sense => disabled
```

and when the button is pressed the IN register bit 17 is `low`, when released it’s `high`.

However, with button B, GPIO pin 26, configured exactly the same, IN register bit 26 is always `low`.

The factory image recognises both button A and B.

Button B is correctly connected to edge connector pin 11 (checked voltage level at edge connector with DVM).

I’d like to know why I have to specify `pullup`, though, given that there’s already a 10k pull-up resistor on the board (and the DVM shows proper logic levels).

The schematic is [here](https://github.com/bbcmicrobit/hardware/blob/master/SCH_BBC-Microbit_V1.3B.pdf), the nRF51 reference manual is [here](http://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/pdf/nRF51_RM_v3.0.pdf).

I found an earlier schematic where GPIO pin 26 was shared with the magnetometer, could that be related?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that

- I use RTC1 to simulate the missing SysTick
- RTC1 uses the low-frequency clock
- I set up the low-frequency clock as if it’s running off a crystal (which it is not!) This means that pin 26’s GPIO functionality is taken over by the expected 32,768 kHz crystal input, so the GPIO is disconnected from it.

Cure: set up the low-frequency clock to run off the 32,768 kHz synthesized output from the high frequency clock.